# Routing in laravel, resolving URL in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

So I'm trying to understand routing in laravel, without much success I'm afraid. My current issue is that I am trying to route so that my login function, which is checked using ajax, is accessible from all pages on the site. At the moment i can only reach it from my index. i use the following

```
Route::post('login', array('uses' => 'LoginController@doLogin'));
```

and the following ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<%= ResolveUrl("~/login") %>",
        data: "username="+username+"&password="+password,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            if(data == 'Fel användarnamn eller lösenord.') {
                document.getElementById('loginerror').innerHTML = data
            } else if (data == 'Inloggad'){
                document.getElementById('loginerror').innerHTML = data;
                window.location.reload(true);
            }
```

Now it is to my understanding that resolving the URL would possibly solve my issue. However, no matter i manipulate the url part, I cant get the resolve to work. I only get syntaxerrors or bad request errors. If there's something built in into laravel for this, to get the correct route independently of changes in the URL, I would greatly appreciate any tip of such functionality. I cant find/understand anything in the documentation that would solve my problem. Else if anyone could tell me how to write the ResoleUrl correctly, that would also be greatly appreciated. however an understanding of laravels routing would probably serve me better! Thanks beforehand!

Comment: Is this AJAX inside a `.blade.php` file?

Comment: the ajax is inside a javscript file, linked into a .blade file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the url in your ajax to:

```
url:"/login"
```

Comment: wow.. Well, I thank you for that! kind of exaclty what i was looking for! however, it still doesn't work, I get a the following instead: POST http://localhost/login 404 (Not Found). do I need to change something in the route itself aswell?

Comment: @user3084471 didn't realise you were on localhost. Assuming your working in a subfolder such as `localhost/myapp` ? If so then you can either `/myapp/login` (it will work, but you will have to change it if you change the subfolder or you go live to a real domain with no subfolder). The other alternative is to set the domain in laravel app/config/app.php to your "base url" such as `localhost/myapp` then use the built in url resolver `URL::to('login')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your route.

```
Route::any('login', ['uses' => 'LoginController@doLogin', 'as' => 'login']);
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. unfortunatley it didn't work. get the following error: POST localhost/login 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Let Laravel do it for you.

Name your route...

```
Route::post('login', array('uses' => 'LoginController@doLogin', 'as' => 'ajax.doLogin'));
```

Link to your route by the name in Javascript...

```
url: "{{ URL::route('ajax.doLogin') }}",
```

Comment: Can you do that in an external javascript file? Will blade be resolved?

Comment: No but you can put it into a new `.blade.php` file in the views folder and include it via blade `@include('yourfile')`