# How to write url in ajax in laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, url, laravel-5, routes

I want to call **storeProduct** controller method in ajax URL.

url: './product_catalog/storeProduct'

How to call a method in this URL?

I want to store product_id and campaign id in the database.

Page not found error occurs.

Route :

```
Route::get('product_catalog','front\ProductCatalogController@showProductCatalogForm');

Route::post('product_catalog',['as' => 'storeProduct', 'uses' => 'front\ProductCatalogController@storeProduct']);
```

Ajax :

```
$(".my_form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    var product_id = $(this).find('#product_id').val();
    var campaign_id = $(this).find('#campaign_id').val();
    console.log(product_id);
    console.log(campaign_id);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: './product_catalog/storeProduct',
        data: {
            'product_id': product_id,
            'campaign_id': campaign_id
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Controller :

```
public function showProductCatalogForm()
    {
        //if($_GET["campaign"]!=="") 
            $campaign=$_GET["campaign"];

        return view('front.product_catalog');
    }

    public function storeProduct(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, $this->rules);

        $input=Input::all();
        $campaign_product=ProductCatalog::create($input);
        return redirect('product_catalog');
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Routing in laravel, resolving URL in ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133515/routing-in-laravel-resolving-url-in-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

your route should be

```
Route::get('/product_catalog','front\ProductCatalogController@showProductCatalogForm');
```

your ajax url should be

```
type: "POST", 
        url: '/product_catalog',
```

Or you can use `route();` i recommend dont use `url()` because any time if you want change `urls` you will need to change it manually.which is not good for app.urls could be 100 or 1000 to change.it could be dangers.

you should try name route like this

```
Route::get('/product_catalog','front\ProductCatalogController@showProductCatalogForm')->name('product_catalog');
```

and your ajax url

```
type: "POST", 
        url: {{ route('product_catalog') }},
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  url: {{ url('/product_catalog/storeProduct') }},
```

Comment: Providing some description abut how it works helps understand the answer

Answer (score 0):

Why you are adding "." In  `./product-catalog` !
Just use `/product-catalog`
Use `"."` when you want to search for folder or any directory or any file in  your project directory or any other folder and you are not sure where the file is
Dont use in url when there is a route for the link

Answer (score 0):

try this if you have wrote javascript inside blade :

```
$(".my_form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    var product_id = $(this).find('#product_id').val();
    var campaign_id = $(this).find('#campaign_id').val();
    console.log(product_id);
    console.log(campaign_id);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '{{route('storeProduct')}}',//this is only changes
        data: {
            'product_id': product_id,
            'campaign_id': campaign_id
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this without the dot before slash.

```
url: '/product_catalog/storeProduct',
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
url:"{{route('route.name')}}"
```

and it works for me. You could check it by

```
console.log("{{route('route.name')}}");
```

inside your script.